# In Django, can I mark a model so that all Foreign Keys to this model will get raw_id_fields, rather than a dropdown

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, foreign-keys

I have a model that is going to have a LOT of instances (it's got to do with logging). Because of this, every model that has a foreign key to this model, I'll have to give it a custom ModelAdmin to set the foreign key to a `raw_id_field`, because a dropdown is going to slow the page down.

Can I mark this on the 'logging' model itself, so that all Foreign Keys have this property?

Comment: I think you can define django admin widget when registering an admin model. You may be able to set the widget to raw text